# completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed が起こる

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sdl

### やったこと

https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.28.4/docs/README-macos.md

の下記手順に従い、インストールしました。

```
mkdir build
cd build
../configure
make
sudo make install
```

ターミナルでは実行できました。

```
$ g++ -o hoge.exe main.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2 -I/usr/local/include/
$ ./hoge.exe
```

### エラー

しかしXcodeでは下記エラーです。

```
dyld[23486]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: <xxxxxxxxxxx> /Users/user-name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/firstsdl-xxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug/firstsdl
  Reason: tried: '/Users/user-name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/firstsdl-xxxxxx/Build/Products/Debug/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/system/introspection/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib' (code signature in <xxxxxxxxx> '/usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib' (code signature in <xxxxxxx> '/usr/local/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib' not valid for use in process: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.), '/usr/lib/libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 6
Program ended with exit code: 6
```

リンクの様子：
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

インクルードの様子：
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 質問

ad-hoc signedとはなんでしょうか？
自分でコンパイルしたのに、署名しないとXcodeでは動かないのでしょうか？
（そもそも、このエラーにおける署名（signed）とはどのようなもので、勝手にやってしまっていいものでしょうか？そもそもやりかたがわかっていませんが）